# Unexpected behavior traversing array given beginning and ending memory addresses in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, dynamic-arrays

Gives the following discrepancy when printing an array:

Output of last run, given array size of 10:

```
1054923524,536171146,1590310503,900411369,764853670,471563977,933417110,1800497411,544592671,135121
1054923524,536171146,1590310503,900411369,764853670,471563977,933417110,1800497411,544592671,0,
```

Any idea why does it prints "0" instead of what I thought? (the last digit of the array)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main() {
  srandom(time(NULL));
  printf("Size:");
  int n;
  scanf("%d",&n);
  int *ints;
  ints=malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
  int i;
  for(i=1; i<n-1;i++) {
    int a=random();
    ints[i]=a;
    printf("%d,",a);
  }
  printf("%d\n",ints[n]);
  sort(&ints[0],&ints[n]);
  free(ints);
}

void sort(int *begin, int *end) {
  int i;
  for(i=0;&(begin[i])!=end;i++) {
    printf("%d,",begin[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please don't [cast the result of malloc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: Thanks. Changed that. The problem persists though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never stored anything into the last element of the array `ints[n-1]`. You print the wrong last element of the array, which invokes undefined behavior, since you are reading beyond the end of the allocated memory area.

Change your initialization loop to initialize all members, by looping while `i < n`. Remove your `printf()` following the loop, and instead, just print a newline character.

```
  for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
    int a=random();
    ints[i]=a;
    printf("%d,",a);
  }
  putchar('\n');
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't catch that.

Comment: @user2452830: The suggested changes I provided should be all you need to do to get the print loop in your `sort()` function to print the same numbers you print during initialization (except for the last newline).

Comment: I must not have read it completely the first time. That was very helpful. You're right; I created more problems by trying to change other things. This completely solves the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are two mistakes:

1. The element at index n - 1 is never initialized as your first loops only goes from 0 to n - 2.
2. The element at index n is beyond the allocated memory.

So the last element you print has index n on the first run, and index n - 1 on the second run.

The fix could look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main() {
  srandom(time(NULL));
  printf("Input desired size of array:");
  int n;
  scanf("%d",&n);
  int *ints;
  ints=malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
  if(ints==NULL) {
    perror("malloc returned NULL");
    exit(1);
  }

  int i;
  for(i=0; i < n; i++) {
    int a=random();
    ints[i]=a;
    printf("%d,",a);
  }

  sort(&ints[0],&ints[n],0);
  free(ints);
}

void sort(int *begin, int *end, int ascending) {
  int i;
  for(i=0;&(begin[i])!=end;i++) {
    printf("%d,",begin[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll change that and try again.

Comment: Stll some problem though; now outputs:1821250995,624166897,1892989986,204514006,2053074628,1250179355,964072650,1085680991,1771083365,1316936590,1316936590
1821250995,624166897,1892989986,204514006,2053074628,1250179355,964072650,1085680991,1771083365,

Comment: So you don't have to actually look at that: It printed 11 numbers first, then printed 9.

Comment: Changed the condition on the loop while storing elements to: i<n and changed the call to sort to: sort(&ints[0],&ints[n-1],0)

Comment: Also, as pointed out by jxh, removed the printf after the for loop so the 11th number is no longer there. Still only get 9 numbers later though.

Answer (score 0):

`printf("%d\n",ints[n]);`

That's an overflow, its undefined behavior. you want `printf("%d\n",ints[n-1]);`